# Grunt: minify js across project of multiple dirs, so that the contents of each dir flattens to a single minified file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, minify

I have a project, with javascript files structured something like this:

[image: Hypothetical directory structure]

My goal: I would like to **minify/uglify these javascript files** in the build output, **such as there is 1 minified file per each directory**.    So for example, if I'm storing the js in my build output in bld/js, then in bld/js, I would end up with files: dir1.min.js (result of concatenating and minifying fileA.js, fileB.js, and all the other js files in /src/js/dir1/), dir2.min.js (result of concatenating and minifying fileG.js and fileN.js, and all the other js files in /src/dir2/), and so on.

Now - **I am using the grunt framework to generate the build**, and must do this within a grunt file.  I am new to grunt, node.js, and javascript.  **I wanted to explain my thought process towards solving this problem, and am wondering if someone more familiar with these frameworks can tell me if my approach/thinking towards this is what is wrong.**

So as I understand, the main way to do things in grunt, is to use plugins.  And so my first thought was to use a plugin to accomplish this task.  There is a plugin called 'npm-contrib-uglify', which is used specifically for minification.  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify  The problem is - my understanding is that to do what I'm hoping to do here (1 min.js file per each directory), I would need to create specific tasks for each directory.  so the init looking something like this:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
      uglify: {
        dir1: {
          files: {
            'dest/js/dir1.min.js': ['src/js/dir1/**.js']
          }
        },
        dir2: {
          files: {
            'dest/js/dir2.min.js': ['src/js/dir2/**.js']
          }
        },
...
        dirN: {
          files: {
            'dest/js/dirN.min.js': ['src/js/dirN/**.js']
          }
        },
      }
    });
```

If I only had one or two dirs, and the project format was going to stay relatively the same - I guess I could live with this.  But there are many dirs in this project, and more importantly, the project structure will be changing; I'd like to be able to add dirs to my project, and not have to update the grunt file each time as a result by adding a new target.  I hoped for a way to parameterize the task - meaning, have a single generic target that says 'for some dir, minify all the .js files in that dir to some .min.js file' and then I could invoke the target programmatically for each dir - but this doesn't seem possible.

So I decided to avoid the plugin, and just rely on node.js.  There is an npm module called 'npm-uglify.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js .  I thought I can make my own custom grunt task, which loops through the source directory, and calls uglify-js on each nested dir.  Here is an example (note I am using pseudocode in a couple places, particularly, for getting the dir listing, as I do not have access to a machine, and do not have the syntax committed to memory.  But this should give the idea of what I mean to do:)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var uglifyJs = require('uglify-js');
```

...

```
grunt.registerTask('minifyMyJs', function(myJsSrcDir) { // myJsSrcDir is an abs. path to the src dir

    for (dir in myJsSrcDir): // go through all the dirs.. realize I should use fs.readdir, but just use pseudocode here to give the idea
        var minifiedOutputFileName = fs.basename(dir); // to get dir1 from /src/js/dir1
        var minified = uglifyJs.Minify(["**.js"]);
        fs.writeFile(minifiedOutputFileNam, result.code, function(err)) {
           if(err) {
              ... error checking...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Now - I'm not asking for you to solve this problem for me, and I know the above would not compile.  Rather my question is - am I just thinking about this in the completely wrong way?  **Is the whole point of grunt to avoid coding things like this in node.js (and so I'm defeating the purpose by doing this?)**  Is it that you really can parameterize the targets of the grunt plugins such as grunt-contrib-uglify?  I am running in to this same issue with many plugins, where I have some task I need to repeat over and over across many different dirs/files but in the exact same way, and so I'd like to be able to configure a general target I can call programmatically for different values (rather than hardcoding tons of targets for specific directory or filenames which could change often).  But this doesn't seem possible, and so I keep just implementing in node.js instead.  **Is there something fundamentally flawed with the way I am approaching grunt?  And if so - can you offer some alternate perspective?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Thoughts

> am I just thinking about this in the completely wrong way?

No, I don't think you are thinking about this in the wrong way. It's always a good thing to question the *why/how* for any development [period]. This is what makes us better developers long-term.

Whichever solution/tools you choose to utilize for your build process, whether that be a dedicated task runner such as [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), or a higher level solution such as [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) perhaps combined with [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), you still have to craft some code. Of course, the commonality between all those approaches mentioned is that you have to code using *JavaScript*.

> Is the whole point of grunt to avoid coding things like this in node.js (and so I'm defeating the purpose by doing this?

It's not for me to say which solution/tool is better to use than another *(that would be too opinionated)* and personally I have had experience developing build processes using all those tools mentioned. Typically though I often find my development time for handling builds is reduced when using a dedicated task runner (*grunt* or *gulp*) than when using a more custom approach such as `npm-scripts` combined with `nodejs`.

Often, I too find a really great plug-in for *grunt* (such as `grunt-contrib-uglify`) to then discover after some tinkering that it meets 90% of my requirements, yet fails miserably for the remaining 10%. However, that's often the case when utilizing/integrating any open sourced package/module... You still have to fill the gaps so to speak!

---

#### Grunts lesser known gems

Before ditching `gruntjs` and going into `nodejs` only development mode just yet, *(and again to reiterate I have no bias towards any of the approaches)*, I recommend that you check-out some of grunts features such as:

- [custom-tasks](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks)
- [grunt.file.expand](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand)
- [grunt.config](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config)
- [grunt.task.run](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run)

There has been may scenarios when using *grunt* that I've found utlizing the features listed above has helped me to address that remaining 10% of the requirement that I mentioned previously. The custom-tasks feature in particular has proved very useful many times.

---

#### Solution

It's worth noting that [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) is a [multi-task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks) plugin. I.e. It allows you to configure multiple [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) as you have demonstrated in the your `uglify` configuration in your question. You have included three Targets named `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dirN`.

With the fact that `grunt-contrib-uglify` is *multi-task* and keeping in mind the grunt features I listed previously... One approach to meet your requirement using *grunt* is to:

1. Use a custom Task to dynamically configure and run the uglify task.
2. Utilize `grunt.file.expand`to get the paths to the parent folder of each .js file.
3. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) paths Array to only unique directory paths.
4. Dynamically create the `files` configuration for each Target of the `uglify` task.
5. Configure the `uglify` task with multiple Targets using `grunt.config` and then run the task using `grunt-task.run`.

---

**Grunfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      // <-- Intentionally blank, will be dynamically generated.
    }
  });

  /**
   * 1. Helper custom Task to dynamically configure and run the uglify task.
   */
  grunt.registerTask('myUglify', 'Configures uglify task', function () {
    var srcDirGlob = 'src/js/**/*.js';
    var destDir = 'dist/js/';
    var config = {};

    // 2. Get the paths to the parent diretory of each .js file.
    var paths = grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isFile' }, srcDirGlob)
        .map(function (_path) {
          return _path.substring(0, _path.lastIndexOf("/"));
        });

    // 3. Filter paths Array to only unique directory paths.
    paths.filter(function(_path, pos){
          return paths.indexOf(_path) === pos;
        })

        // 4. Dynamically create the `files` configuration for each Target.
        .forEach(function(_path, index) {
          var dirName = _path.substring(_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          var destPath = destDir + dirName + '.min.js';
          var srcGlob = _path + '/*.js';

          config[index] = {
            files: {}
          }

          config[index].files[destPath] = srcGlob;
        });

    // NOTE: The dynamically created `config` object is now something like this:
    //
    //    config: {
    //      0: {
    //        files: {
    //          'dist/js/dir1.min.js': 'src/js/dir1/**.js'
    //        }
    //      },
    //      1: {
    //        files: {
    //          'dist/js/dir2.min.js': 'src/js/dir2/**.js'
    //        }
    //      },
    //      ...
    //    }

    // 5. Configure the uglify task with multiple Targets
    //    (i.e. the `config` object) and then run the Task.
    grunt.config('uglify', config);
    grunt.task.run(['uglify']);
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ["myUglify"]);
};
```

**Results**

Running `$ grunt` via your CLI using the `Gruntfile.js` above with a `src` directory as follows:

```
.
└── src
    └── js
        ├── dir1
        │   ├── fileA.js
        │   └── fileB.js
        ├── dir2
        │   ├── fileG.js
        │   └── fileN.js
        └── dir3
            ├── fileQ.js
            └── fileR.js`
```

..will concatenate and `uglify` the `.js` files producing a directory structure as follows:

```
.
└── dist
    └── js
        ├── dir1.min.js
        ├── dir2.min.js
        └── dir3.min.js`
```

*Note: The parent folder name of the source `.js` file is used for the name of the resultant concatenated/uglified `.js` file.*

---

#### Summary

- The pattern/approach utilized in the `Gruntfile.js` (above) can be modified as necessary for many of the the plug-ins available.
- As long as the plugin itself supports *Multi-Tasks* then consider utlizing a *grunt Custom Task* to fill in the gaps.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: RobC - your approach for dynamically generating the config content is exactly what I was lacking in my understanding of grunt.  I am going to play around with it like this.  I had gotten the impression that you could only set the configuration once, and then once you did grunt.loadNpmTasks(<plugin>), that whatever configuration had been set in initConfig, was there for good.  The fact that you can generate the configuration dynamically within a custom task (or some other function) changes a lot in how I can approach this (and other grunt plugins).  Thanks for this valuable insight.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also require other node modules in the `Gruntfile.js` too. For example purposes; In the `forEach` function, where I obtain the `dirName` and `destPath` values it's probably possible to require nodes builtin [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module and utilize that API instead. Remember _gruntjs_ is built on _nodejs_. _(I tried to keep my gist as vanilla as possible)_ If after some time you feel my answer is correct please consider accepting it. Thanks!