# Grunt: How to run a function and then a task and then another function, sequentially, when the functions can not be split in to different tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, scheduled-tasks

I am using Grunt to generate a build.  I am new to Grunt, javascript, and nodejs, so any new perspectives would be welcomed.

Some of the tasks in my Gruntfile rely on plugins (such as 'uglify' for javascript minification), while there are some other workflows that are best suited to just writing javascript functions themselves.

I keep running in to situations where I need to do the following: (1) execute a javascript function (2) run a grunt task immediately after that function (3) execute another javascript function.  It needs to happen in that order.  However, since Grunt is just a task scheduler, it ends up running (1), queuing (2), running (3), and then running (2) as the final step, after (1) and (3) have completed.

The following is a very simple use case for a hypothetical custom task, to explain the situation better.

```
grunt.task.registerTask('minifyJS', function() {

    jsFilepathMapping = configureUglifiy();
    /** note - configureUglify is needed because the minification filepaths
        are generated on the fly, I do not know them before the script runs
        and more than that, there are so many that it would be really bulky
        to create init targets for each single minification file that needs
        to be generated.*/

    grunt.task.run('uglify');

    updateJsScriptTags(jsFilepathMapping); // update the <script> tags in my HTML

});
```

The problem is that I need to run these things in the order shown above.
However, since grunt is a task scheduler, the following happens instead, when this task is run

1. **configureUglify()** function will **run**.
2. **'uglify'** will get **queued** - NOT run.
3. **updateJsScriptTags()** function will **RUN**.
4. Now that the default task has completed - **only now will 'uglify'**, which was queued up, will **run**.

Now, I understand WHY this happens.  Grunt is a task scheduler - the tasks are getting queued up.  This makes sense and not complaining about it.  **Rather, I'm asking what is the way to resolve this?  So that I can achieve this ordering, when using this combination of functions and tasks?**  I imagine this must be super simple and common, I just don't know what it is!

*One option I realize* is to convert each of those functions in to tasks themselves.  However, the problem with this, is that the configureUglifiy() returns a complex data structure, which updateJsScriptTags() then consumes.  There does not seem to be a great way to share data between Grunt tasks, other than using the 'options' attribute, which is only available within tasks themselves.  I guess I could do this, however, my concern here is that this makes things unreadible and... kind of dangerous, since you now have this task, that is relying on a data structure being modified during another task, and it's not immediately obvious until you start digging in the function.

Let me give an example.  Which is more readable to you?

```
/** 
    documentation which defines what the argment filepathMapping is

    Furthermore, since the function takes an argument, the context is
    immediately clearer just looking at the function declaration.
*/
function updateJsScriptTags(filepathMapping) {

    // do stuff ...
    for ( key in filepathMapping ) { // oh cool!  i know what this arg does, my documentation nicely explains it, and its structure too
         // lots of stuff
    }
}

...
// and elsewhere in the script, where it's being invoked:

var aMapping = someFunc();
updateJsScriptTags(aMapping);
```

vs.

```
grunt.task.registerTask('updateJsScriptTags', 'update js tags', function() {

   // do stuff.
   ...

    // many lines later:
    grunt.options('filepathMapping') // Oh, what is this attribute?  Let me go look around the rest of the script to find out where it comes from

}

...
// and ultimately, where it's being invoked.
grunt.task.run('someTask'); // global options param gets modified somewhere in here, but you'd never know it looking at this line of code
grunt.task.run('updateJsScriptTags'); // this task will depend on that modification
```

I find this makes things more unreadable, as opposed to a simple function that takes in arguments to be consumed, and can impose a particular structure.  It also seems easier for things to get buggy the other way where I'm modifying a bunch of attributes in some global param within one task, which gets consumed later in another.  Even more bothersome, is the attribute names being shared, are hardcoded..  I know that this is a very simple use case, but start to imagine a more complex set of functions that rely on multiple arguments which could be complex data types, and that is where my concern goes.

**So as a quick summary: are there alternatives to achieving a sequential ordering of function/plugin-task/function/plugin-task, without resorting to converting the functions to custom tasks themselves?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So as a quick summary: are there alternatives to achieving a sequential ordering of function/plugin-task/function/plugin-task, without resorting to converting the functions to custom tasks themselves?

**Short answer:** No, to maintain the order of execution you need to define order using grunt Tasks and not plain JavaScript functions.

Sequential ordering is carried out by the order of each [alias-task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) defined in the `taskList` Array. For example when using `grunt.registerTask`:

```js
grunt.registerTask('foo', [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]);
```

Given the pseudo example above and running the `foo` Task will run task `a` first, followed by task `b`, and so on *(I.e. Task `b` will not run until Task `a` completes; Task `c` will not run until Task `b` completes)*.

However that doesn't mean to suggest that it's not possible to utilize plain JavaScript functions in combination with grunt [custom Tasks](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks).

---

**Long answer with solution:**

> There does not seem to be a great way to share data between Grunt tasks...

You can use an `Object` to store the data. The pseudo code in your first example implies that you want the `configureUglifiy` function to:

1. Dynamically configure the `Uglify` Task
2. return data (an `Object`) which is generated by `configureUglifiy` itself.
3. Then pass the returned data as an argument to the `updateJsScriptTags` function.

So, instead of returning an `Object` from the `configureUglifiy` function. You can store it in another `Object`, which is then subsequently accessed in the `updateJsScriptTags` function.

In the following gist take note of the `shared` Object, with a property/key named `jsFilepathMapping`. We'll use this object to store dynamically generated data which can be accessed in another task.

**Gruntfile.js** *(pseudo code)*

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  var shared = {
    jsFilepathMapping: {} // <-- Intentionally empty. The object will
                          //     be defined via `configureUglify` function,
                          //     and consumed by `updateJsScriptTags` Task.
  };

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      // <-- Intentionally empty, will be dynamically generated.
    }
  });

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Functions
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  /**
   * Helper function to dynamically configure the uglify task.
   */
  function configureUglify() {

    // <-- Do stuff here to determine configuration of uglify task.

    grunt.config('uglify', config);

    // Store object (for referencing later) instead of returning.
    shared.jsFilepathMapping = config;
  };

  /**
   * Helper function to update the js script tags in html.
   */
  function updateJsScriptTags(filepathMapping) {

    // `filepathMapping` object now available in this function.
    for ( var key in filepathMapping ) {
      console.log(filepathMapping[key])
    }
  }

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Tasks
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  grunt.task.registerTask('updateJsScriptTags', 'Updates tags', function () {

    // Invoke the function passing in the values which were previously
    // ascertained and set via the `configureUglify` function.
    updateJsScriptTags(shared.jsFilepathMapping)
  });

  grunt.task.registerTask('minifyJS', function() {
    configureUglify();
    grunt.task.run(['uglify']);
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Define sequential ordering of each Task in the taskList Array.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['minifyJS', 'updateJsScriptTags']);
};
```

**Note** The comment that reads `// <-- Do stuff here to determine configuration of uglify task.` will be logic similar to the *Gruntfile.js* gist that I provided to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323641/grunt-minify-js-across-project-of-multiple-dirs-so-that-the-contents-of-each-d#answer-47333787).

---

**Summary**

1. Sequential ordering should be defined by adding Tasks to the `TaskList` Array (as per the *short answer* section above)
2. Functions can be invoked via grunt Custom Tasks when necessary. But remember a Custom Tasks is a function so only separate logic out to it's own function when it's really necessary to do so. You'll find your *Gruntfile.js* reads better.
3. When one task/function dynamically obtains data to share between other tasks/functions consider storing it in a `Object` instead of returning values from functions using the `return` keyword.
4. Where possible separate the logic into individual defined tasks, and try to avoid doing too much in one Task. For example, in the first custom task that you provided in your question named `minifyJS` you are trying to do two things in one Task. I.e. You're configuring and running your uglify task (which constitutes to one task), and also updating the the JS script tags (which constitutes to another task). This ideally should be two separate distinct tasks.

The pseudo `Gruntfile.js` that I provided (above) it not currently adopting my advice given in points 2 and 4. With some refactoring the `Gruntfile.js` would be more like this (Note the functions no longer exists and instead their logic has been combined with the Custom Task that invoked them):

**Gruntfile.js** *(pseudo code refactored)*

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  var shared = {
    jsFilepathMapping: {} // <-- Intentionally empty. The object will
                          //     be defined via `minifyJS` Task,
                          //     and consumed by `updateJsScriptTags` Task.
  };

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      // <-- Intentionally empty, will be dynamically generated.
    }
  });

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Tasks
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  grunt.task.registerTask('updateJsScriptTags', 'Updates tags', function () {

    // `filepathMapping` object now available in this task.
    for ( var key in shared.jsFilepathMapping ) {
      console.log(shared.jsFilepathMapping[key])
    }
  });

  grunt.task.registerTask('minifyJS', function() {

    // <-- Do stuff here to determine configuration of uglify task.

    // Save object (for referencing later) instead of returning.
    shared.jsFilepathMapping = config;

    grunt.config('uglify', config);
    grunt.task.run(['uglify']);
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Define sequential ordering of each Task in the taskList Array.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['minifyJS', 'updateJsScriptTags']);
};
```