# How to run the same grunt task with different configurations (programmatically)?

Tags: gruntjs

I've trawled the web for the last 2 hours trying to figure out how to do this so I'm asking here. I've read the documentation but I can't find a good example and I think I may be implementing some sort of anti-pattern or I have missed something very basic but here goes.

I want to loop around an array and perform this task in each loop

```
grunt.task.run('string-replace:dist');
```

However, every time I run this loop I need a slightly different config. Different output folder, different replacement array etc etc

I have been changing the config like this.

```
  grunt.config.set('string-replace.dist.options.replacements', translationsArray);
  grunt.config.set('string-replace.dist.files.0.dest', 'dist/' + langCode + '/');
```

Here comes the problem. Grunt does not seem to execute tasks, wait for them to finish and then continue with your code. So it sets up the task for each loop but does not run it, then it changes the config for each loop overwriting the old config each time. Then it runs all the tasks with the last config. I just want to make Grunt execute the task, wait till its done, change the config, rinse and repeat.

Am I doing something really stupid? Grunt documentation seems to be desperately telling me its synchronous but this does not seem to be the case with `grunt.task.run`. I would also like to point out that I don't want to just register more tasks with the different options because I don't know how many times I might have to run this loop. It is controlled from elsewhere so it can be dynamic and data driven. Unless I'm supposed to register tasks dynamically?

Comment: You say _"I don't want to just register more tasks with the different options"_ (note: I think you mean "Targets" and not "Tasks") so dynamically create [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets)'s instead. Consider configuring your `string-replace` Task so that it starts out as a empty object in `grunt.initConfig`, e.g. `grunt.initConfig({ 'string-replace': {} });`. Then create a [custom RegisterTask](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks), in which you loop your Array and dynamically configure the `string-replace` Task with a new "Target" per ...

Comment: ... each config/setting defined in your Array. After dynamically generating each target you invoke the `string-replace` Task using `grunt.task.run(['string-replace'])` from inside the same custom `RegisterTask` - this effectively runs all Targets defined in the `string-replace` Task once the custom `RegisterTask` in invoked. Then when you want to run the `string-replace` Task you invoke the custom `RegisterTask` instead. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323641/grunt-minify-js-across-project-of-multiple-dirs-so-that-the-contents-of-each-d/47333787#47333787) that ...

Comment: ... shows an `Gruntfile.js` example of the aforementioned approach - it should help to further understand. Without knowing what the "Array" is that you want to loop around makes it difficult to provide a more concrete example/answer - likewise for the `translationsArray` array. In summary; using this approach you avoid calling `grunt.task.run` multiple times, instead you dynamically configure multiple "Targets" and call `grunt.task.run` once which in turn calls a Task that contains predefined/dynamically configured "Targets" - all done from within a custom `RegisterTask`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I figured out a way to achieve what I wanted by registering a new task for each loop and setting the config options inside it before calling the string-replace task. I understand your method and may implement it if it provides a benefit over my current solution.

Comment: You're welcome @lorless. Please consider posting your solution/method as an answer so that others can benefit from it.